# Remove temporary captured video produced by UIImagePickerController

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller

I use the following codes to capture video in `UIImagePickerViewController`:

```
- (IBAction)openVideoPicker:(id)sender {
    self.video_picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.video_picker.delegate = self;
    self.video_picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        self.video_picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        self.video_picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];
    }
    else
    {
        self.video_picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    }
    [self presentViewController:self.video_picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

When I browse the files in Sand Box, there are a lot of videos capture in `/MyApp/tmp/capture` folder. Since they occupy quite a lot amount of file size. When will these temp files be removed ? or can I remove them manually via programming?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21246429/950290) you can do this programmatically:

```c
NSString *videoPath = @""; // path to your video
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath: videoPath]) {
    NSError *error;
    // Attempt to delete the folder containing videoPath
    if ([fileManager removeItemAtPath: [videoPath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] error: &error] != YES) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to delete file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```